# Rails - Have form show specific attribute based on boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named **Package Request** and a model named **Item**. In the Item model, I have an attribute named **Availability** which is a boolean value. In the **Package Request** form, I have an option to select an item from the **Item** table. How do I only show items that only have the boolean value marked as true? In other words, how do I only show items that are available?

Please let me know if you need to see any specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scope in the Item model

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord 
  scope :available, -> {where(availability: true)}
```

Now you can build the item table using `Item.available` insted of `Item.all`